# Remove first letter in element with Javascript (ES6)

Tags: javascript

The goal of this script is to remove the first letter of a block of text - `firstLetter` - and replace it with `newFirstLetter`.

```
const initialLetter = (firstParagraph) => {
  let firstLetter = firstParagraph.innerHTML.charAt(0)
  let newFirstLetter = "<span class='initial-letter'>" + firstLetter + "</span>"
  let paragraphContent = firstParagraph.innerHTML
  // this is not working
  paragraphContent.substr(0, 1)
  // this is working
  firstParagraph.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', newFirstLetter)
}
```

So far, this line `firstParagraph.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', newFirstLetter)` is working as intended, but this line `paragraphContent.substr(0, 1)` is not removing the first letter in that block of content. I am wondering what I am doing wrong here?

The current output of this script is:

```
 <p><span class="initial-letter">E</span>Every day we see the potential technology provides to create better pathways of care—for the people delivering care and the patients they treat who are managing their own chronic disease(s). Rock Health reported that since 2011, $23B has been invested in thousands of digital health companies. Yet, historically, innovative solutions for kidney disease have been static at best and from a funding perspective, largely very quiet.</p>
```

Comment: `substr` does not modify the string. It returns a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in javascript are immutable, so you can't just change it, you need to reassign the changed version back to the innerHTML

```js
let p = document.getElementById('p')
const initialLetter = (firstParagraph) => {
  let firstLetter = firstParagraph.innerHTML.charAt(0)
  let newFirstLetter = "<span class='initial-letter'>" + firstLetter + "</span>"
  let paragraphContent = firstParagraph.innerHTML
  firstParagraph.innerHTML = paragraphContent.substr(1)
  // this is working
  firstParagraph.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', newFirstLetter)
}
initialLetter(p)
```

```css
span.initial-letter {
  color:red
  }
```

```html
<p id='p'>Every day we see the potential technology provides to create better pathways of care—for the people delivering care and the patients they treat who are managing their own chronic disease(s). Rock Health reported that since 2011, $23B has been invested
  in thousands of digital health companies. Yet, historically, innovative solutions for kidney disease have been static at best and from a funding perspective, largely very quiet.</p>
```

Comment: I see. That makes sense, thank you! This works, will accept answer when I can in a couple of minutes :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can just slice the first letter and just attach something new to it

```js
var field = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
var edited = document.getElementById("edited");

var newField = field.slice(1);

edited.innerHTML = "This is after slice: " + newField;

console.log(newField);
```

```html
<div id="test">Hello</div>
<div id="edited"></div>
```